# Drawing a confidence ellipse on top of a scatter plot

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I'm currently working on an iOS app where I'm using the CorePlot library (Version 2.1) to draw a scatter plot. My scatter plot draws fine, and in the next step I'd like to draw an translucent confidence ellipse on top of the plot. I've written a class computing the main and minor axis and the required rotation angle of my ellipse. My ConfidenceEllipse class implements a getPath() method which returns a CGPath representing the ellipse to draw.

```
func getPath() -> CGPath
{
var ellipse: CGPath

var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (transform, CGFloat(-self.meanX), CGFloat(-self.meanY))
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate (transform, CGFloat(self.angle))
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (transform, CGFloat(self.meanX), CGFloat(self.meanY))

ellipse = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake (CGFloat(-self.mainHalfAxis), CGFloat(-self.minorHalfAxis), CGFloat(2 * self.mainHalfAxis), CGFloat(2 * self.minorHalfAxis)),&transform)

return ellipse
}
```

After searching the web for a while, it appears that Annotations are the way to go, so I tried this:

```
let graph     = hostView.hostedGraph!
let space     = graph.defaultPlotSpace    
let ellipse = ConfidenceEllipse(chiSquare: 5.991)
ellipse.analyze(self.samples)

let annotation = CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation (plotSpace: space!, anchorPlotPoint: [0,0])
let overlay = CPTBorderedLayer (frame: graph.frame)
overlay.outerBorderPath = ellipse.getPath()

let fillColor = CPTColor.yellowColor()
overlay.fill = CPTFill (color: fillColor)

annotation.contentLayer = overlay
annotation.contentLayer?.opacity = 0.5
graph.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Doing this, will give me the following
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZyO8.png)
As you can see, the overlay takes up the full size of the frame, which seems logical given the fact that I passed the frames dimensions when creating the **CPTBorderedLayer** object. I also tried leaving the constructor empty, but then the overlay doesn't show at all. So I'm wondering, is there anything I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scale the ellipse to match the plot. Use the plot area `bounds` for the frame of the annotation layer and attach the annotation to the plot area. Scale the ellipse in the x- and y-directions to match the transform used by the plot space to fit plots in the plot area.

Edit:
After looking into how bordered layers work, I realized my suggestion above won't work. `CPTBorderedLayer` sets the `outerBorderPath` automatically whenever the layer bounds change. Instead of trying to affect the layer border, draw the ellipse into an image and use that as the `fill` for the bordered layer. You should size the layer so the ellipse just fits inside.

Comment: You're right, I forgot scaling the ellipse. I tried to initialize the border annotation with both the bounds of the plot area and of the ellipse, the later scaling the border annotation so that it fully covers the area with dots on the scatter plot, but unfortunately the ellipse still doesn't show. The annotation still shows as a rectangle. Do you reckon me setting the outerBorderPath is the culprit? This occured to me after reading the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588862/changing-the-layer-shape-for-cptplotspaceannotation.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to get the Annotations to work properly, I decided to take a different road. My final solution consists in overlaying my original scatter plot with a second one, which only contains one datapoint, namely the center of my confidence ellipse. Here's the code

```
    func drawConfidenceEllipse () {

    let graph     = hostView.hostedGraph!
    let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as! CPTXYPlotSpace

    let scaleX = (graph.bounds.size.width - graph.paddingLeft - graph.paddingRight) / CGFloat(plotSpace.xRange.lengthDouble)
    let scaleY = (graph.bounds.size.height - graph.paddingTop - graph.paddingBottom) / CGFloat(plotSpace.yRange.lengthDouble)

    let analysis = ConfidenceEllipse(chiSquare: 5.991)
    analysis.analyze(self.samples)
    let unscaledPath = analysis.getPath()

    let bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(unscaledPath)

    var scaler = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    scaler = CGAffineTransformScale (scaler, scaleX, scaleY)
    scaler = CGAffineTransformTranslate (scaler, CGFloat (-bounds.origin.x), CGFloat (-bounds.origin.y))
    let scaledPath   = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath (unscaledPath, &scaler)
    let scaledBounds = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(scaledPath)

    let symbol = CPTPlotSymbol ()
    symbol.symbolType = CPTPlotSymbolType.Custom
    symbol.customSymbolPath = scaledPath
    symbol.fill = CPTFill (color: CPTColor.yellowColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.25))
    symbol.size = CGSize (width: scaledBounds.size.width, height: scaledBounds.size.height)

    let lineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 1
    lineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.yellowColor()

    symbol.lineStyle = lineStyle

    let ellipse = CPTScatterPlot (frame: hostView.frame)
    ellipse.title = "Confidence Ellipse"
    ellipse.delegate = self
    ellipse.dataSource = self
    ellipse.plotSymbol = symbol
    ellipse.dataLineStyle = nil

    graph.addPlot(ellipse)
```

}

Here's a screenshot of the final result:

[95% Confidence Ellipse on top of scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRvIU.png)

Hope this helps